# SCP always returns the same error code

Tags: qt, ssh, scp

I have a problem copying files with scp. I use Qt and copy my files with scp using QProcess. And when something bad happens I always get exitCode=1. It always returns 1. I tried copying files with a terminal. The first time I got the error "Permission denied" and the exit code was 1. Then I unplugged my Ethernet cable and got the error "Network is unreachable". And the return code was still 1. It confuses me very much cause in my application I have to distinct these types of errors.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: "in my application I have to distinct these types of errors" That means you'll probably need to implement ssh & scp in your program, instead of invoking an external utility that doesn't do what you need it to do.

Comment: If you are only interested in those two, you could work with other Qt Classes to check for permissions and network accessibility before invoking scp:

Permissions QFile::permissions()
QNetworkAccessManager::networkAccessible()

Comment: I second @Kenster and advise you to use libssh or libssh2. It is not difficult to write a Qt wrapper just for scp.

Comment: you could also use readAllStandardError() to parse the error

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

See this code as a working example:

```
bool Utility::untarScript(QString filename, QString& statusMessages)
{
  // Untar tar-bzip2 file, only extract script to temp-folder
  QProcess tar;
  QStringList arguments;
  arguments << "-xvjf";
  arguments << filename;
  arguments << "-C";
  arguments << QDir::tempPath();
  arguments << "--strip-components=1";
  arguments << "--wildcards";
  arguments << "*/folder.*";

  // tar -xjf $file -C $tmpDir --strip-components=1 --wildcards

  tar.start("tar", arguments);

  // Wait for tar to finish
  if (tar.waitForFinished(10000) == true)
  {
    if (tar.exitCode() == 0)
    {
      statusMessages.append(tar.readAllStandardError());
      return true;
    }
  }

  statusMessages.append(tar.readAllStandardError());
  statusMessages.append(tar.readAllStandardOutput());
  statusMessages.append(QString("Exitcode = %1\n").arg(tar.exitCode()));
  return false;
}
```

It gathers all available process output for you to analyse. Especially look at readAllStandardError().